# Equivalent? No, but why?

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

T-SQL:

1(ANSI):    `convert(varchar(10),@DueDate, 102) < convert(varchar(10),getdate(), 102)`

2(USA):    `convert(varchar(10),@DueDate, 101) < convert(varchar(10),getdate(), 101)`

Notice that these will return different results when year is considered.

Why?

What's the difference? Why isn't the operator taking year into consideration when using #2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do? You're comparing varchars, there. Look at the output from these statements:

```
print convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
print convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
```

That prints this:

```
01/14/2009
2009.01.14
```

Comparing the first form is only really going to be checking to see if the month of one date is less than the month of the current date.

Is there a reason you need to convert the dates to varchar? Why not compare them directly?

```
@DueDate < getdate()
```